# How to feed links to CSV files gathered by SitemapSpider into second spider that is CSVFeedSpider

Tags: scrapy

I have a sitemap spider that can gather links to csv files.  I would like to use a csv spider to crawl over those links.  How would I go about feeding the output of one spider into another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See an example from [official documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=csvSpider#csvfeedspider-example):

```
from scrapy.spiders import CSVFeedSpider
from myproject.items import TestItem

class MySpider(CSVFeedSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/feed.csv']
    delimiter = ';'
    quotechar = "'"
    headers = ['id', 'name', 'description']

    def parse_row(self, response, row):
        self.logger.info('Hi, this is a row!: %r', row)

        item = TestItem()
        item['id'] = row['id']
        item['name'] = row['name']
        item['description'] = row['description']
        return item
```

To use it with a local file instead, just use file url: `file:///home/user/some.csv`

Comment: What I'm trying for now is the SitemapSpider is populating a database with the links to the csv files and the CSVFeedSpider is reading from that database.

Comment: @tylerjw why not just store everything in a database and cut the csv middleman? For scrapy documment driven databases like mongo or couchdb work brilliant or if you don't have much data redis is a super easy solution!

Comment: I am using a mongo database for storing results.  The problem is that there is more specific data in that csv file that I want than is shown in the list view on the page.  I eventually figured out the arguments for the uri for the csv api so I don't even have to load the page with the link on it.